# GKE with Istio routing on 2 clusters

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, istio

i want to improve my service accessibility to customers.
currently i have 1 cluster on "europe-west zone" with istio with 10 services (more or less).
with deployments, virtual services and services and one shared volume between the services
and istio internal routing between the services.

i want to create additional cluster on "us zone" and create a duplicate of "europe cluster"
with all istio configuration i have on the original "europe cluster".

which means that user from US will hit my service on "us cluster"
and user from Europe will hit "europe clsuter" with same domains.

The problem i had after setting up the "us cluster" is that i currently have two load balancers - one for "us cluster" and one for "europe cluster".
In such a situation, i have a problem with the routings.
My idea was to add a third loadbalancer on top of it, which is responsible for the router according to the user's zone, but I could not configure such a thing.

tnx.

**edit:**
in my case istio manage all the routing and he is the loadbalancer.

Comment: You could expose your services using Network Endpoint Groups and attach them as backend to a single LB, you could use this as reference [link](https://blog.doit-intl.com/how-to-setup-multi-cluster-load-balancing-with-gke-4b407e1f3dff), does this work for your use-case?

Comment: i have tried to do that but without any succeeded.
istio is my tcp load balancer and all routing and the traffic Goes through it.
i defined my dns to istio loadbalancer and with the link he created a new http load balancer which mean the istio goes to nowhere.

Comment: I guess it is possible to replace the TCP Load Balancer if you define the istio-ingress-gateway as a Nodeport, then you can add it as a NEG backend in a HTTPS LB, take a look at this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/integrating-https-load-balancing-with-istio-and-cloud-run-for-anthos-deployed-on-gke), eventhough it uses Cloud Run you should be able to do it in a regular GKE cluster. Another option would be to use [multi-cluster ingress with Anthos](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/multi-cluster-ingress) but it requires a licence